# I can't access req.session variables in other post requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, session

I am developing an apt management app.

Basically, if a user is a resident, they get to see their apt fee payment data.

If the user is from apt management, they select one of the 5 db update options from the apt mgmt menu page by clicking one of the submit buttons numbered from 1 to 5.

I am trying to make my code session-based so I am attaching my own variables to `req.session` object as `req.session.loggedin`, `req.session.userid` and `req.session.userpwd`.

I authenticate `username` and `userpwd` inputs from login page in the first post request to `'/server'` and if they match in db then I set `req.session.loggedin` to `true`.

I was hoping that I would be able to use the `req.session.loggedin` and `req.session.username` variables in the second request to `'/mgtmenupg'` and other requests but unfortunately it doesn’t work because I get undefined error.

At the moment I can’t progress any further. What do I have to do to able able to access `req.session.loggedin` and `req.session.username` variables in other requests?

Any help will be appreciated.

Attached is my minimal reproducable examples of js code.

```js
var express = require('express');  // Import Express package
var session = require('client-sessions');
//var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');  // Import body-parser module to parse incoming requests  
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var path = require('path');  //import path module.
var app = express();  // Create an Express app variable so that we can use Express in anywhere.
var router = express.Router();
var cors = require('cors');  //import cors from "cors". CORS allows frontend and backend to share data because they are on different servers. 
var port = 3000;  //Set port to 3000. This is where our backend server will be.
var mysql = require('mysql'); 
var alert = require('alert');
const { config } = require('process');
//var { response } = require('express');
var con = mysql.createConnection({   // Create connection object.
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'hsAdmin',
    database: 'havuzsDB'
}); 
//const { request } = require('http');
// Below, we use the imported modules in our Express app.
app.use(express.json() );   // use Express module body-parser to parse JSON-encoded request bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true})); // use Express module body-parser to parse URL-encoded request bodies
app.use(cookieParser());
// Use the sessions package to determine if user is logged-in.    
app.use(session({
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'top99secret',
    duration: 30 * 60 * 1000,
    activeDuration: 5 * 60 * 1000,
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: true,
    ephemeral: true
    //resave: true, 
    //saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(cors());
// Set up view engine.
app.engine('html',require('ejs').renderFile);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
//app.set('views', path.join(_dirname, 'views'));

// Start your server on a specified port and listen for http request on that port.
// app.listen() is the function that starts a port and host, in our case the localhost for the connections 
// to listen to incoming requests from a client. 
app.listen(port, () => {
    alert("server is running at http://127.0.0.1:", port);   //Show server url at console. Use this url in <script> tag of your html code. 
 });

/* You can use this to check if your server is working. 
app.get('/', (req, res)=>{
    res.send("Welcome to my server");
}); */

// Connect to havuzsDB database. 
con.connect(function(err) {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
            alert("DB Connection failed"); 
            }
        else
            alert("DB Connected!");
}); 

// Route to send the local image file to be used as app homepage background, to the client. 
app.get('/havuzlusite-img.jpg', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/havuzlusite-img.jpg"); 
});

// Route to send home page file to the client.
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/homepg.html");
});

// Route to send the login form to the client. 
app.get('/loginpg', function(req, res) {    //Send login page file to the client.
    res.sendFile("D:/Behrans-files/Web-projects/havuzlusite/loginpg.html");
});

//Route to receive and authenticate user login data.
app.post('/server', (req, res) => {  
    req.session.username = req.body.isim; // save username input in a local variable. 
    req.session.userpwd = req.body.sifre; // save user pwd in a local variable.
    if (req.session.username && req.session.userpwd) {  //Check if user has entered name and password in the login form.
        con.query('SELECT * FROM havuzs_sakinleri WHERE isim = ? AND sifre = ?', [req.session.username, req.session.userpwd], function(err, rows) {
            if (rows.length > 0) {
                req.session.loggedin = true;
                req.session.rows = rows;
            } else {
                return alert('İsim ve şifre veri tabanında bulunamadı. Lütfen geçerli bir isim/şifre girin!');
                //return res.render('loginpg');
            }           
            res.end();
        })
    } else {   
        return res.send('Lütfen isim ve şifre giriniz!');
        res.end();
    }  

    //console.log('loggedin:', req.session.loggedin, 'username: ', username);
    //If user is a resident, display resident data.
    if (req.session.loggedin && req.session.username !== 'Yonetim') {    
        if (req.session.rows) {  // If user name/pwd match db,
            var rows = req.session.rows;
            return res.render('userdatapg', {rows});  // Display resident data.
            res.end;
        }    
    };    

    //If user is an authorized building management team member, display management menu.
    if (req.session.loggedin && req.session.username == 'Yonetim') {       
        return res.render('mgtmenupg');  //Display db update menu page.
        res.end();
    }        
});

// Determine which button is clicked. 
app.post('/mgtmenupg/:btnno', (req, res) => {    
    
    // Route to handle apt fee payment - If button#1 is clicked.
    if (req.params.btnno == 1) {   
        res.render('userpmtpg');  //Display user apt fee payment page.
        app.post('/userpmtpg', (req, res) => {  //Post request to access payment month and payment amount inputs from user.  
            var username = req.body.username;
            var pmtmnth = req.body.pmt_mnth;
            var pmtamt = req.body.pmt_amt;
            queryusername(username, function(response) {  //Pass username and call function to see if the user is in db.
                if (response == 'Found')  { //If response has no error message, call function to update user payment data in db.
                    updateUsrPmtData(username, pmtmnth, pmtamt, function(response) { //Call function to update user apt fee payment data in db.
                        return alert(response);   //Display db update status message from called function.
                     });    
                } else if (response == 'Not found')
                            res.send('İsim veri tabanında bulunamadı. Ana sayfaya dönmek için lütfen Ana sayfa butonuna tıklayınız!'); //If response has error message, display error message.     
                        else 
                            res.send('Site sakini ismi veri tabanında aranırken sorun oluştu.');
            })
            res.render('mgtmenupg');
            res.end();            
        })
    }     

    // Route to handle deletion of existing resident user - If button#2 is clicked.
    if (req.params.btnno == 2) {  
        res.render('deluserpg');
        app.post('/deluserpg', (req,res) => {
            var username = req.body.username;
            queryusername(username, function(response) { //Pass username and call function to see if the user is in db.
                if (response == 'Found')  { //If response has no error message, it means user is in db, call function to delete it.
                    deleteUser(username, function(response) { // Pass username input data as parameter to call deleteuser function.
                        return alert(response);  //Display db delete status message from called function.
                        res.render('mgtmenupg');
                    })  
                } else if (response == 'Not found') {
                          return alert('İsim veri tabanında bulunamadı. Lütfen sistemde mevcut bir isim girin.'); //If response has error message, display error message.     
                          return res.render('deluserpg');
                        } else 
                            return res.send('Site sakini ismi veri tabanında aranırken sorun oluştu.');                                               
            })
            res.end();    
        })
    };
```

Comment: `… to use the req.session.loggedin and req.session.username variables in the second request to '/mgtmenupg' and other requests but … I get undefined error.` what is the exact error message you get? And where? In the shown code you  access `req.session` only in `app.post('/server'`, I don't see any other route where it is used.

Comment: Ever since I changed my code to be session based, things have become very inconsistent. I can't follow what is happening because in the first post request to '/server', when I log the req.session.loggedin variable in the console, it is printed as undefined, but the req.session.username is printed correctly. I don't don't even use these variables in the second post request because I get undefined console error. So, I try to stay within the first post request to '/server' and do the authentication there but as I said above even there, at the moment, my console log shows it undefined.

Comment: I keep making changes in the hopes of getting it to work but as soon as I make a tiny little change, it causes unpredictable results. I am getting tired and wondering if I should give up.

Comment: It is important that you stay calm and to answer what you are asked. `when I log the req.session.loggedin variable in the console, it is printed as undefined, but the req.session.username is printed correctly.` I only see one `console.log` that is for `req.session.loggedin` but that’s commented out, do you mean that one? `I don't don't even use these variables in the second post request because I get undefined console error.` Please show the exact error message and the code resulting in that error.

Comment: Yes, I uncommented it out after posting my question. I made other minor changes such as commenting or uncommenting 'res end()' lines, removing or adding ';' after the '})' etc. These are minor cosmetic changes to me but even a minor change such as adding ';' after'})' has totaly unpredictable results. So my code has changed since I posted my question. I have other problems as well. For example, after a login with a valid user name/pwd or with an invalid username/pwd, the processing doesn't stop, the little circle to the left of the page title keeps spinning.

Comment: Also, when I try displaying a page via res.render or res.redirect, I get a white page. So perhaps the best thing for you to do is to tell me how to code the authentication section. If user is a resident, I want to display user's data from db. If user is apt mgt, I want to display the management menu. If username/pwd is invalid, I want to display a message and go back to the login page. Once I get this working, I can handle the rest.

Comment: Again please calm down, take a deep breath, and focus on that one problem. If you don't answer the questions you are asked precisely and instead mention other problems you have it won't be possible to give you help in a meaningful way.

Comment: Below is the output from the console.log.                                                                        
             loggedin: undefined username:  Ayse Meydaner                                                                                                                                       As you can see, loggedin is undefined but the username is correct. This user and the entered pwd are in the db, so loggedin is set to true as you can see in the code. But, when I print it in console.log few lines below, it is undefined. How can this be?

Comment: Regarding the `//console.log('loggedin:', req.session.loggedin, 'username: ', username);` resulting in `undefined`. This is related to  [How to return the response from an asynchronous call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321), you set `req.session.loggedin = true;` in the asynchronous callback of your database query. So `req.session.loggedin = true;` happens **after** your `console.log`. That has nothing to do with session handling, but a behavior you will encounter with almost any APIs in nodejs.

Comment: Regarding `I don't don't even use these variables in the second post request because I get undefined console error`. You still didn't say how and where you tried to access those session variables in the other post request. Without that information, it is impossible to tell you what you did wrong there.

Comment: I am not getting anywhere. This session thing is not making things easier. I have removed it from my code and now it works perfectly. My logic is simple. If user has logged in, then I proceed. If not, then I display a suitable message and return to login page. If an invalid username/pwd is entered, I display a suitable message and return to login page. Simple and straightforward and it works. Thanks for your time and comments. I think I wasted stackoverflow resources needlesly.

Comment: I finally figured it out. It was the that async call in 'con.query ("SELECT....)' that was causing all the confusion and throwing me off. I was doing the authentication outside that async call as opposed to inside it. Now I am doing it inside and I am able to access the req.session variables in all post requests and my code works perfectly. This finding should be posted for others as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: that’s what I wrote 14 hours ago in my [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69630770#comment123089415_69630770) with a link to a question explicitly talking about that topic. But your question is about `I can't access req.session variables in other post requests`.